# Is there a REST API Reference available for AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services

As far as I understand, there are only three ways to access AWS resources:

1. Management Console (browser)
2. AWS CLI
3. AWS SDK (in various programming languages)

However, why did not AWS provide REST APIs and their reference document so that we can interact with AWS resources directly using a REST client like Postman?

I think they are using REST APIs behind the scenes (All the above three interactions actively use REST API I guess).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is REST API documentation available as well. Its just that AWS officially encourages the use of more abstract methods such as using CLI and SDK since its easier to use as well as they are maintained by AWS.

Also using the sdk or cli is encouraged because they are perfectly interfaced with the aws rest api with extensive testing and covering all cases. And you don't need to focus on stuff like what headers you need to attach or what should be the request body format. Users can focus on writing their own business logic.

The only source I could find for documentation of rest api are the official docs which I have linked below. Since the direct use of rest api is not preferred hence no commonly available tutorials. I don't think there is anything extra which can be accomplished using the rest api which the cli or sdk doesn't already offer.

A more practical example would be aws s3 cli. It has a lot of underlying implementation which speeds up the process of uploading and downloading, like establishing 10 network connections in parallel to utilize the complete network bandwidth etc. This you would have to implement yourself if you are directly using the api.

Some Examples: 
[S3 REST API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/s3-api.pdf#Type_API_Reference)
[EC2 REST API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/ec2-api.pdf#Welcome)

Similarly there is API documentation available for every service.

Comment: Sure I will Rohan. I was just checking if there are any other answers from anyone. I still have one question - why doesn't AWS recommend using the API directly as well? Many tutorials still say that there are only 3 ways to interact with AWS (which I mentioned above). Is there any article or something which shows us readily available examples to try out with Postman etc? Please ket me know. Yes, I'll mark this as answered later today definitely. Thanks very much.

Comment: Great! I updated the answer to make the point more clear. Though if you have some particular use case in which you directly need to use the REST API, I could help out with that.